Comping `gcc` for different host/target CPU
I am on a system where I need to compile gcc-14 and clang-19 from scratch. The host CPU has the characteristics [1] and the target has [2]. So far my strategy to compile gcc was as follows:
# git clone the relevant repo and cd into it
# checkout the 14 branch and run
./configure                                                             \
        --program-suffix=-14                                            \
        --disable-multilib                                              \
        --enable-languages=c,c++                                        \
        --host=x86_64-linux-gnu                                         \
        --build=x86_64-linux-gnu                                        \
        --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
make -j 
make install

This worked in the sense that you I get a working C++ compiler. After that I wanted to compile onetbb using conan. The conan profile used for this is
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=23
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=14
os=Linux

and running
conan install --requires="onetbb/" -pr:a=profile 

results in this error:
onetbb/2021.12.0: RUN: cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/buildagent/.conan2/p/b/onetbef908189cd23f/p" -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091="NEW" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" "/home/buildagent/.conan2/p/b/onetbef908189cd23f/b/src"
-- Using Conan toolchain: /home/buildagent/.conan2/p/b/onetbef908189cd23f/b/build/Release/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake
-- Conan toolchain: Defining architecture flag: -m64
-- Conan toolchain: C++ Standard 23 with extensions OFF
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 14.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++-14 - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Checking for one of the modules 'hwloc'
-- IPO enabled
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 14.2.0
-- CMAKE STUFF
-- The tbbbind_2_5 target will be configured using the HWLOC 2.9.3
-- CMAKE STUFF

onetbb/2021.12.0: Running CMake.build()
onetbb/2021.12.0: RUN: cmake --build "/home/buildagent/.conan2/p/b/onetbef908189cd23f/b/build/Release" -- -j128
[48/49] Linking CXX shared library gnu_14.2_cxx23_64_release/libtbb.so.12.12
FAILED: gnu_14.2_cxx23_64_release/libtbb.so.12.12
: && /usr/local/bin/g++-14 -fPIC -m64 -O3 -DNDEBUG -flto=auto -fno-fat-lto-objects  -m64  -Wl,--version-script="/home/buildagent/.conan2/p/b/onetbef908189cd23f/b/src/src/tbb/def/lin64-tbb.def"  -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libtbb.so.12 -o gnu_14.2_cxx23_64_release/libtbb.so.12.12 src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/address_waiter.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/allocator.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/arena.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/arena_slot.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/concurrent_bounded_queue.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/dynamic_link.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/exception.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/governor.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/global_control.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/itt_notify.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/main.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/market.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/tcm_adaptor.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/misc.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/misc_ex.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/observer_proxy.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/parallel_pipeline.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/private_server.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/profiling.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/rml_tbb.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/rtm_mutex.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/rtm_rw_mutex.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/semaphore.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/small_object_pool.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/task.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/task_dispatcher.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/task_group_context.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/thread_dispatcher.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/thread_request_serializer.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/threading_control.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/version.cpp.o src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/queuing_rw_mutex.cpp.o  -ldl  -pthread && :
/tmp/ccfEljbQ.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccfEljbQ.s:20084: Error: no such instruction: `tpause %edi'
make: *** [/tmp/ccf5lKfr.ltrans0.ltrans.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/cc5qEUcQ.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc5qEUcQ.s:15719: Error: no such instruction: `tpause %edi'
/tmp/cc5qEUcQ.s:16832: Error: no such instruction: `tpause %ecx'
make: *** [/tmp/ccf5lKfr.ltrans2.ltrans.o] Error 1
lto-wrapper: fatal error: make returned 2 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

So it seems that the host cpu is missing some instructions that are needed to compile onetbb. Now, this is not really a problem since the target CPU has the instructions needed...
So the questions is: how do I get this setup to correctly compile executables on host that will run on the target. Im not sure I just need to add some flags to the conan settings that will be passed to onetbb when its compiled. Or do I need to make sure gcc is somehow specifically compiled?
References

host CPU characteristics

> lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              128
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-127
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  64
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        4
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               49
Model name:          AMD EPYC 7742 64-Core Processor
Stepping:            0
CPU MHz:             3399.657
CPU max MHz:         2250.0000
CPU min MHz:         1500.0000
BogoMIPS:            4500.00
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-15,64-79
NUMA node1 CPU(s):   16-31,80-95
NUMA node2 CPU(s):   32-47,96-111
NUMA node3 CPU(s):   48-63,112-127
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr wbnoinvd arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip rdpid overflow_recov succor smca sme sev sev_es


target CPU characteristics

>lscpu
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   12
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-11
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6128 CPU @ 3.40GHz
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                85
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   6
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             4
    CPU max MHz:          3700.0000
    CPU min MHz:          1200.0000
    BogoMIPS:             6800.00
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca c
                          mov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm
                          pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_per
                          fmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid ap
                          erfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl smx est tm2 s
                          sse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic
                           movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand
                           lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 p
                          ti intel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust
                           bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a av
                          x512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt av
                          x512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cq
                          m_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida
                           arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req pku o
                          spke md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                    192 KiB (6 instances)
  L1i:                    192 KiB (6 instances)
  L2:                     6 MiB (6 instances)
  L3:                     19.3 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):           1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):      0-11
Vulnerabilities:
  Gather data sampling:   Mitigation; Microcode
  Itlb multihit:          KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
  L1tf:                   Mitigation; PTE Inversion
  Mds:                    Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Meltdown:               Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:        Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Reg file data sampling: Not affected
  Retbleed:               Mitigation; IBRS
  Spec rstack overflow:   Not affected
  Spec store bypass:      Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:             Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sa
                          nitization
  Spectre v2:             Mitigation; IBRS; IBPB conditional; STIBP conditional; RSB
                           filling; PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected; BHI Not affected
  Srbds:                  Not affected
  Tsx async abort:        Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable


You aren't really cross compiling in the traditional sense, you probably just need an appropriate -march flag when you complete

The specific error is related to the tpause instruction, which is part of Intel's Thread Director technology and requires specific CPU support. I would suggest disabling IPO by the recipe option: conan install --requires="onetbb/" -pr:a=profile -o "onetbb/*:interprocedural_optimization=False". That option is enabled by default.

@AlanBirtles I thought/hoped so... Looking at the output of lscpu it seems that skylake-avx512 might be a good try.

@uilianries Hmm, is there no way how to get it to compile without disabling functionality? Tbh, Im not sure if it makes a difference, but preferably we would like to keep everything as it was so far (so far we compiled on the target directly)..

@Sito In case you want to try extra march flags instead, you could use the Conan configuration tools.build:cxxflags:  -c "tools.build:cxxflags=['-march=skylake-avx512']" More info about supported configuration you can obtain in Conan docs: https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/global_conf.html
